# Randomly selecting between N maximal values and returning key in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, random, dictionary, idioms

Suppose I have a FruitDetector class which takes in a string and returns the possible types of fruit with different probabilities as a hash:

```
type = {
  banana: 0.2,
  lemon: 0.4,
  orange: 0.4
}
```

What would be the cleanest, most idiomatic way to select one random element from the N maximal values in the hash (in this case, to randomly select between lemon and orange), returning the name of the fruit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to do it step by step:

```
# determine maximum weight
maxw = type.values.max

# select items with maximum weight
selection = type.select{|item, weight| weight == maxw}

# choose random item from selection
p selection.keys.sample
```

Comment: Just change `.map{|item, weight| weight}` to `.values` and this is pretty good.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Of course you are right. I had a different expression before, but `.values` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing (based on your answer, but shorter):

`types.select { |i,j| j == types.values.max }.keys.sample`

Does this seem right? Will `types.values.max` be re-computed at each iteration?

Comment: @louism Yes it will be recomputed at each iteration. And `sample` is a good idea, didn't think of that.

Comment: Good, so the shortest efficient way is:
`maxw = types.values.max; `

`selection = types.select { |i,j| j == maxw }.keys.sample`

Answer (score 1):

```
type.group_by{|k, v| v}.max.last.sample.first
```

Comment: This also works but would have to be edited to add .first at the end (otherwise it returns an array):
`type.group_by{|k, v| v}.max.last.sample.first`.
Its cleaner, but it is twice slower (@Howard, see [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/1579661)) than the previous solution, so I'm keeping the other one as the accepted answer.